# run azure cli against a specific storage account

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to run the following az storage cli command to add CORS settings:

```
az storage cors --account-name mystorage --origins '*' --methods GET,POST,PUT --allowed-headers 'Accept-Ranges,Content-Encoding,Content-Length,Content-Type,Range,Authorization,x-ms-blob-content-type,x-ms-blob-type,x-ms-version' --exposed-headers 'Accept-Ranges,Content-Range,Content-Encoding,Content-Length,Content-Type' --max-age 86400 --services blob
```

BUt I get the following error:

> az storage cors: 'mystorage' is not in the 'az storage cors' command group. See 'az storage cors --help'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include operation type (`add` in this case). Please try the following:

```
az storage cors add --account-name my storage --origins '*' --methods GET POST PUT --allowed-headers 'Accept-Ranges,Content-Encoding,Content-Length,Content-Type,Range,Authorization,x-ms-blob-content-type,x-ms-blob-type,x-ms-version' --exposed-headers 'Accept-Ranges,Content-Range,Content-Encoding,Content-Length,Content-Type' --max-age 86400 --services b
```

Two more things I noticed in your command:

1. Methods should be space separated and not comma separated. So it should be `--methods GET POST PUT` instead of `method GET,POST,PUT`.
2. Service should be "b" for blob.